# Writing equation of motion in matrix form

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

How can I write the equation of motion of a system of N variables: `x1, x2, ..., xN`, (these are all functions of time) in matrix form?

For example,

```
m*x1'' = -K * x1 + K * x2;
m * x2'' = K * x1 - (k + K) * x2 + k * x3;
m * x3'' = k * x2 - (k + K) * x3 + K * x4; 
m * x4'' = K * x3 - K * x4;
```

Comment: This question may belong to the math or physics forum, but this one is about the *Mathematica* software package, and you may be in the wrong place.

Comment: No, I want to write the equation of motion in matrix form using Mathematica.

Comment: Maybe if you told us what the equations are in non-matrix notation, we could translate?

Comment: (1) m*x1''=-K * x1 +K * x2; (2) m * x2'' = K * x1 - (k+K) * x2 + k * x3, (3) m * x3'' = k * x2 - (k+K) * x3 + K * x4, (4) m * x4'' = K * x3 - K * x4

Comment: @Hamza, Could you edit you initial post, adding the equations there instead of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]};
A = {{-K, K, 0, 0}, {K, -k - K, k, 0}, {0, k, -k - K, K}, {0, 0, K, -K}};
Thread[m*x''[t] == A.x[t]]
```

> {m x1"[t] == -K x1[t] + K x2[t], 
>      m x2"[t] == K x1[t] + (-k - K) x2[t] + k x3[t], 
>      m x3"[t] == k x2[t] + (-k - K) x3[t] + K x4[t], 
>      m x4"[t] == K x3[t] - K x4[t]}

Note that the symbol `K` is already in use in *Mathematica*; you should use something else instead.