# Show tabulated equations in matrix form

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, list-manipulation

How do i put last equation, `eqm[x, t, k, n]` into matrix form? 
I want every row to end with `== 0`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 3; 
Subscript[k, (j_)?EvenQ] = κ; 
Subscript[k, (j_)?OddQ] = k; 
Subscript[k, (j_)?0] = ko; 
Subscript[k, (j_)?n + 1] = ko; 

ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
  (1/2) *
    Sum[
      Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j - 1][t] - Subscript[x, j][t])^2,
      {j, 1, n + 1}]; 

te[x_, t_, n_] := 
  (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}]; 

lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n]; 

eqm[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
   Sum[D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Subscript[x, j][t], 1}], {j, 1, n}] - 
   Sum[D[D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t], 1}], 
     {t, 1}], {j, 1, n}];

MatrixForm[eqm[x, t, k, n]] == MatrixForm[0]
```

I want it to look like this but with zero on the other side

[image]

For `n = 3` It should look like this:

[image]

I tried array, but I'm bad at such stuff! I was able to do it correctly some time ago. It was short. Unfortunately,  I deleted some files, so I lost the correct code.

Comment: why you vote down !?
This is regular question!

Comment: The output of `eqm[x, t, k, n]` is a single equation. What do you mean by "putting it in matrix form"? Also, avoid subscripts if you can; they tend to complicate expressions needlessly. You will also notice that `MatrixForm[0]` doesn't really make much sense. Show us an example of the output you seek.

Comment: check now i edit added a pic

Comment: duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194153 ?

Comment: every j in the sum in eqm generate a dimension and row for the matrix.
how using array and tables can i sort them put them finally in matrix form.

i did it sometime ago but deleted some old files so i got lost !

Comment: @Roman  i saw that post but never helped !

Comment: I think your `(j_)?0` and `(j_)?n+1` patterns make no sense. After the question mark is supposed to be a function with one argument that returns `True` or `False` when used on the argument.

Comment: i know i did it some weird way

Answer (score 3):

this one way to do it !

```
q1 = Table[eq[x, t, k, n][[j]], {j, 1, n}] // Simplify
q2 = Table[eq[x, t, k, n][[j]], {j, n + 1, 2 n}]

MatrixForm[q1 + q2] == MatrixForm[Table[0, {j, 1, n}]]
```

[image]